# Event get's ignored by discord bot when another exists. (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot using [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) whose primary function is to type out a story when the command is given. **Only 2 commands exists**: One is a help function and the other is to start the story. The command for help is `r!help` while the comman to start the story is `r!start` however for some reason the **bot doesn't seem to recognize that `r!help` has been sent by a user and only responds to `r!start`.** Below is my code for these events.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')

# bring up help

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!start'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Starting Story...')

#start story
```

My IDE (pycharm) doesn't show me any errors, the bot seems to be online on the server and does repond to `r!help` with `starting story`. It just dosen't respond to the help command.
I did notice that when the `r!start`event had been commented out, the help event did work so I would assume that the problem lies within the story event.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')


# bring up help

#@client.event
#async def on_message(message):
 #   if message.content.startswith('r!start'):
  #      channel = message.channel
   #     await channel.send('Starting Spam...')
#works when this section is not there
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're defining the same function twice and thereby changing it again. To have it recognize both you have to put them both in the same function.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!start'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Starting Story...')
    elif message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')
```

Like this you define the function once and don't change it and you check for both commands.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is if you want to separate your code in two functions is to use **`bot.listen`**

Docs: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.listen)

Also if you want a fully commanded bot, you might want to use [discord.ext.commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) and then define several commands with **`@bot.command()`**

Example: [Here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py)